# Flutter initState is called multiple times

Tags: flutter, dart

My code:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:food_delivery/pages/favoritespage.dart';
import 'package:food_delivery/pages/profilePage.dart';
import 'package:food_delivery/pages/shoppingScreen.dart';


class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Food Delivery App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        secondaryHeaderColor: Colors.blue,
        accentColor: Colors.blue,
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        primaryColorDark: Colors.blueAccent,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage()));
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>{

  static Widget _appCache;
  int currentIndex = 0;
  List<Widget> pages;
  Widget currentWidget;
  MyHomePage homePage;
  ShoppingPage shoppingPage;
  FavoritesPage favoritesPage;
  ProfilePage profilePage;
  bool _lights = false;
  String themeText = 'Light';
  BottomAppBar _bar;
  FloatingActionButton _fab;
  Widget _container;
  int _currentPos = 0;

  Widget getContainer(){
    return  Container(
      height: 200.0,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding:  EdgeInsets.only(left: 16,top: 16),
            child: Text('Theme',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
          ),
          SwitchListTile(
            activeColor: Colors.orange,
            inactiveThumbColor: Colors.black,
            title: Text('$themeText',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontWeight: FontWeight.w400)),
            value: _lights,
            onChanged: (bool value) { setState(() {
              _lights = value;
              themeText = value? 'Light':'Dark';
            }); },
            secondary:  Icon(Icons.lightbulb_outline,color: Colors.white,),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
  FloatingActionButton getFab(){
    return FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () {
    
      },
      child: Icon(
        Icons.fastfood,
        color: Colors.black45,
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
      heroTag: null,
    );
  }
  BottomAppBar getNavBar() {
    return BottomAppBar(
        color: Colors.orangeAccent,
        shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        notchMargin: 4,
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Text('1'),
            Text('2'),
            Text('3'),
            Text('4'),
         
          ],
        )
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _bar = getNavBar();
    _fab = getFab();
    _container = getContainer();
    homePage = MyHomePage();
    shoppingPage = ShoppingPage();
    favoritesPage = FavoritesPage();
    profilePage = ProfilePage();
    pages = [homePage,shoppingPage,favoritesPage,profilePage];
    currentWidget = homePage;
    print('init');

  }
  Widget _buildApp() {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        extendBody: true,
        primary: true,
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: true,
        bottomNavigationBar: _bar,
        floatingActionButton:_fab,
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
        body: currentWidget
    );

    
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Colors.deepOrange,
    ));
    if(_appCache==null)
      _appCache = _buildApp();
    return _appCache;
  }

  }
```

I am using a BackdropScafflold but since there is no place for the
bottomNavigation I have used a scaffold inside it to place the BottomAppbar, the layout was rendering properly but after a while the errors started to appear with no apparent reason that I can think of.

My log

```
I/flutter (29504): init
I/flutter (29504): init
I/flutter (29504): init
I/flutter (29504): init
I/flutter (29504): init
I/flutter (29504): init
I/flutter (29504): init
I/flutter (29504): init
I/flutter (29504): init
I/flutter (29504): init
I/flutter (29504): init
I/flutter (29504): init
I/flutter (29504): init
I/flutter (29504): init
I/flutter (29504): init
I/flutter (29504): init
I/flutter (29504): init
I/flutter (29504): init
    ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following StackOverflowError was thrown building RawGestureDetector(state:
RawGestureDetectorState#e7638(gestures: [tap], behavior: opaque)):
Stack Overflow

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  IconButton
  file:///D:/Flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/backdrop-0.4.3/lib/button.dart:42:12

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      _WordWrapParseMode.values (package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart:778:6)
#1      _SyncIterator.moveNext (dart:core-patch/core_patch.dart:165:25)
#2      Iterable.length (dart:core/iterable.dart:429:15)
#3      _PrefixedStringBuilder._finalizeLine (package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart:858:30)
#4      _PrefixedStringBuilder.write (package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart:975:9)
#5      TextTreeRenderer._debugRender (package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart:1279:15)
#6      TextTreeRenderer.render (package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart:1128:14)
#7      TextTreeRenderer._debugRender (package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart:1319:39)
#8      TextTreeRenderer.render (package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart:1128:14)
#9      WidgetInspectorService._reportError (package:flutter/src/widgets/widget_inspector.dart:939:9)
#10     FlutterError.reportError (package:flutter/src/foundation/assertions.dart:1087:14)
#11     _debugReportException (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6034:16)
#12     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4575:9)
#13     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4262:5)
#14     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4525:5)
...     Normal element mounting (4 frames)
#18     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3490:14)
#19     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3258:18)
#20     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4571:16)
#21     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4719:11)
#22     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4262:5)
#23     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4525:5)
#24     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:5)
#25     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3490:14)
#26     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3258:18)
#27     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4571:16)
#28     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4262:5)
#29     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4525:5)
...     Normal element mounting (4 frames)
#33     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3490:14)
#34     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3258:18)
#35     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4571:16)
#36     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4719:11)
#37     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4262:5)
#38     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4525:5)
#39     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4520:5)
...     Normal element mounting (4 frames)
...
...
#5348   RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:115:13)
#5349   RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1769:7)
#5350   RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:115:13)
#5351   RenderOffstage.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:3228:13)
#5352   RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1769:7)
#5353   RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:115:13)
#5354   RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1769:7)
#5355   _RenderTheatre.performLayout (package:flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart:702:15)
#5356   RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1769:7)
#5357   RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:115:13)
#5358   RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1769:7)
#5359   RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:115:13)
#5360   RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1769:7)
#5361   RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:115:13)
#5362   RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1769:7)
#5363   RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:115:13)
#5364   RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1769:7)
#5365   RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:115:13)
#5366   RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1769:7)
#5367   RenderView.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/view.dart:170:13)
#5368   RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
#5369   PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:889:18)
#5370   RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:404:19)
#5371   WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:867:13)
#5372   RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:286:5)
#5373   SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1117:15)
#5374   SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1056:9)
#5375   SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:865:7)
(elided 11 frames from class _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer, dart:async, and dart:async-patch)

════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

The rest of the screens viz(ShoppingPage(),FavoritesPage(),ProfilePage()) are simple widgets with a text wrapped inside a center.

Comment: does it happen if you always call `_buildApp()`? i mean `return _buildApp();` instead of `return _appCache;`?

Comment: yes it does I had returned `_buildApp()` before this I saw that init was being called alot so I decided to use the cache to ensure that `buildApp()` gets called only once. I also tried removing the BackdropScaffold using only the regular Scaffold  but the problem still persists.

Comment: ok so post the minimal not working code: nobody will even try to install some 3rd party package with that `BackdropScaffold`

Comment: sure Ill do that have you ever seen initState being called multiple times?

Comment: Hey I removed some the code using the libraries.
Can you try it out. .

Comment: your `MyHomePage` has a `Scafold` and the `body` of this `Scaffoldi` is `MyHomePage` that has a `Scaffold` and the `body` of this ....

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion

Comment: OH I see silly me. Thanks

Comment: sure, your welcome

Comment: hey real quick, What do you think about Jetpack Compose?

Comment: i dont use it - its alpha afaik

Comment: cool................